# How to map from ViewModel to Model with base properties

Tags: c#, automapper

I want to map ViewModel to Model with base class but without adding base class to ViewModel.

I would like to keep my classes' structure.

I have tried to use Include, IncludeBase, IncludeDerivered but I can't find good configuration.

Here is my code

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(mc => mc.AddProfile(new MappingProfile())).CreateMapper();

        var model = new RegisterViewModel { Name = "TEST" };

        var x = mapper.Map<Register>(model, Guid.NewGuid());
    }
}

public interface ICommand
{
    Guid Id { get; }

    Guid AggregateId { get; }
}

public abstract class Command : ICommand
{
    protected Command() => Id = Guid.NewGuid();

    public Guid Id { get; }

    public Guid AggregateId { get; private set; }
}

public sealed class Register : Command
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
}

public class RegisterViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<RegisterViewModel, Command>()
           .ForMember(x => x.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())
           .AddCommandFields()
           .Include<RegisterViewModel, Register>();

        CreateMap<RegisterViewModel, Register>().IncludeBase<RegisterViewModel, Command>().AddCommandFields();
    }
}

public static class MapperExtensions
{
    private static readonly string AGGREGATE_KEY = "AGGREGATE";

    public static TDestination Map<TDestination>(this IMapper mapper, object source, Guid aggregateId)
    {
        return mapper.Map<TDestination>(source, opt =>
        {
            opt.Items[AGGREGATE_KEY] = aggregateId;
        });
    }

    public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> AddCommandFields<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expression)
        where TDestination : ICommand => expression.ForMember(x => x.AggregateId, opt => opt.MapFromAggregate());

    private static void MapFromAggregate<TSource, TDestination>(this IMemberConfigurationExpression<TSource, TDestination, Guid> expression) => expression.MapFrom((_, __, ___, context) => context.Items[AGGREGATE_KEY]);
}
```

For derived properties Automapper correctly works but base properties are not mapped, although MapFromAggregate is invoked.

**EDIT**

As @Lucian Bargaoanu suggested I wanted to remove extension methods but then I figured out that problem is with method "AddCommandFields".

This code works correctly

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<RegisterViewModel, Command>()
           .ForMember(x => x.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())
           .ForMember(x => x.AggregateId, opt => opt.MapFromAggregate())
           .Include<RegisterViewModel, Register>();

        CreateMap<RegisterViewModel, Register>()
           .IncludeBase<RegisterViewModel, Command>()
          .ForMember(x => x.AggregateId, opt => opt.MapFromAggregate());
    }
}

public static class MapperExtensions
{
    private static readonly string AGGREGATE_KEY = "AGGREGATE";

    public static TDestination Map<TDestination>(this IMapper mapper, object source, Guid aggregateId)
    {
        return mapper.Map<TDestination>(source, opt =>
        {
            opt.Items[AGGREGATE_KEY] = aggregateId;
        });
    }

    public static void MapFromAggregate<TSource, TDestination>(this IMemberConfigurationExpression<TSource, TDestination, Guid> expression) => expression.MapFrom((_, __, ___, context) => context.Items[AGGREGATE_KEY]);
}
```

I have no idea why this extension method breaks my code.

Comment: Try removing all those extension methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the generic constraint is for `ICommand` and there is no setter for `ICommand.AggregateId`. You can change the constraint to `Command` or add the setter for `ICommand.AggregateId`.

Comment: Is it AutoMapper's internal logic? In debugging typeof(TDestination) was Command or Register so I thought interface is not a problem.

Comment: Ok, but I don't get why ICommand is used to check for setter when I explicit use Command/Register